# Find Max Value within a group and copy entire row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the max value within a group (group by:Column A , max value : column E) and copy entire raw to a next sheet in excel.

A-B-C-D-E

1-10-4-2-5.491

1-10-5-2-5.8

1-20-4-3-4.498

2-30-5-3-6.663

2-30-6-4-8.205

2-10-4-5-8.562

3-10-5-6-7.026

3-30-7-2-10.665

3-30-8-2-8.472

4-10-4-1-4.489

4-10-5-1-5.491

4-25-7-3-0.816

My expectation is to get the output as below in another sheet.

1-10-5-2-5.8

2-10-4-5-8.562

3-30-7-2-10.665

4-10-5-1-5.491

Please suggest a solution.(preferred to have a solution in VBA)Thanks.

Comment: `Please suggest a solution` - what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Correct Answer given by Dan Wagner using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a VBA-based solution which builds the following:

[image: start_to_finish]

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindMaximums()

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, MaxSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastDataRow As Long, GroupCol As Long, _
    MeasureCol As Long, CurrentGroup As Long, _
    MaxMeasureRow As Long, RowIdx As Long, _
    LastMaxRow As Long
Dim MaxMeasureValue As Double
Dim DataRng As Range, MaxRng As Range

'identify sheets and columns for easy reference
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set MaxSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Maximums")
GroupCol = 1 'grouping info in column A
MeasureCol = 5 'measure for comparison in column E

'identify the last row to set bounds on our loop
LastDataRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'initialize group and max variables
CurrentGroup = 1
MaxMeasureValue = 0
MaxMeasureRow = 1
LastMaxRow = 1

'loop through all rows
For RowIdx = 2 To LastDataRow

    'check to see if there has been a group change
    If DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, GroupCol).Value > CurrentGroup Then

        'write out the max measure row
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(MaxMeasureRow, GroupCol), DataSheet.Cells(MaxMeasureRow, MeasureCol))
        Set MaxRng = Range(MaxSheet.Cells(LastMaxRow, GroupCol), MaxSheet.Cells(LastMaxRow, MeasureCol))
        DataRng.Copy MaxRng

        'initialize and increment
        CurrentGroup = DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, GroupCol).Value
        MaxMeasureValue = 0
        MaxMeasureRow = 1
        LastMaxRow = LastMaxRow + 1

    End If

    'evaluate max measure logic
    If DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, MeasureCol).Value > MaxMeasureValue Then
        MaxMeasureValue = DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, MeasureCol).Value
        MaxMeasureRow = RowIdx
    End If

Next RowIdx

'write out the last maximums
Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(MaxMeasureRow, GroupCol), DataSheet.Cells(MaxMeasureRow, MeasureCol))
Set MaxRng = Range(MaxSheet.Cells(LastMaxRow, GroupCol), MaxSheet.Cells(LastMaxRow, MeasureCol))
DataRng.Copy MaxRng

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, Im getting an empty value on DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, GroupCol).Value even after the sheet name changed to "Data". Please help.

Comment: Hey @user3494938, the routine I wrote above relies on the "Group" values to be in column A and the "Measure" values to be in column E as shown in the screenshot. Does your data look like that?

Comment: Your code works.. a great solution.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words @user3494938, feel free to modify as you see fit. The 'initalize group and max variables section can be adjusted depending on your data structure

Answer (score 1):

Add a helper formula in column F, call it "max" or whatever, then put this array formula in the first data row (I'm assuming row 2):

```
=E2=MAX(IF(A2=$A$2:$A$13,$E$2:$E$13))
```

Note the array formula needs to be committed by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter (not just Enter).

Fill the formula down.

You now have a column of TRUE/FALSE values. Autofilter this column and select TRUE.

Copy and paste the results to new sheet.

Comment: Your suggestion works. Thanks. But I would preferred to have a VBA solution.

Comment: +1 @andy-holaday, built-in functionality is a great look for problems like these